# Upload Image into sharepoint group folder from angular app

Tags: angular, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, postman

My project is to develop an app with angular to upload images to the SharePoint site, within this project, I am planning to upload images from the Angular app to the **Private SharePoint group folder**. I use Microsoft graph API and Azure AD to get authentication to get access the Sharepoint folder.  Due to my lack of knowledge in angular and SharePoint, I don't have a clear(proper) idea of this process. Anyone can help me with this to get reach my target.

AppAccessToken & TenantId are already in my hand. I've tried testing with Postman?

Within your explanation, I expect the below points.

1. What should I develop in the front-end?
2. Should I create any backend coding from Sharepoint or not? Or can I do this without any back-end coding?
3. How can I use postman to test the apps?
4. How to config MS graph, Angular & Sharepoint?
5. Relationship between Angular, the Sharepoint, MS Graph & Postman.

This is a really important project from my side and Appreciate any answers given.

Answer (score 0):

After studying several tutorials for a couple of weeks, I've found some explanations for my own questions. This might help anyone who is new.

1. What should I develop in the front-end?
   Answer: When uploading files to the SharePoint site, you only need to develop front-end upload HTML to your client-side.
2. Should I create any backend coding from Sharepoint or not? Or can I do this without any back-end coding?
   Answer: Not required any back-end coding due to file only uploaded to the SharePoint site. The rest will be done by Sharepoint.
3. How can I use postman to test the apps?
   Answer: While using Microsoft Graph API & Azure AD Authentication, you can add your Microsoft graph library to the postman, which is supported by Microsoft graph API.
4. How to config MS graph, Angular & Sharepoint?
   Answer: Follow this link.

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RTHY3jScmA
5. Relationship between Angular, the Sharepoint, MS Graph & Postman?
   Answer: These apps do not have any relationship between them and different technologies. But they can use it together to develop customized website.

I believe this will help anyone and any corrections and updates are appreciated.